# Couchbase N1ql query for updating new objet to JSON array

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have the following sample JSON

```
"address":{
    "details":
    [
        {
        "id"        :<system generated UUID>,
        "city"      :{"type"        : "string"},
        "country"   :{"type"        : "string"},
        "name"      :{"type"        : "string"},
        "url"       :{"type"        : "string"},
        "contacts"  :
                [{
                "email":{"type"        : "string"},
                "phone":{"type"        : "number"}
                }]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want the data to be in the following ways 
Example 1:

```
"address":
{
  "details": [
    {
      "id": 1234,
      "city": "Medway",
      "country": "United Kingdom",
      "name": "Medway Youth Hostel",
      "url": "http://www.yha.org.uk"
    }]
}
```

Example 2:

```
"address":
{
  "details": [
    {
      "id": 1234,
      "city": "Medway",
      "country": "United Kingdom",
      "name": "Medway Youth Hostel",
      "url": "http://www.yha.org.uk",
      "contact": [
        {
          "email": "hari34@gmail.com",
          "phone": 6789435634
        }
          ]
    }]
}
```

Example 3 :

```
"address":
{
  "details": [
    {
      "id": 1234,
      "city": "Medway",
      "country": "United Kingdom",
      "name": "Medway Youth Hostel",
      "url": "http://www.yha.org.uk",
      "contact": [
        {
          "email": "hari34@gmail.com",
          "phone": 6789435634
        },
        {
          "email": "sri123@gmail.com",
          "phone": 9876655555
        }
          ]
    }]
}
```

Example 4:

```
"address":
{
  "details": [
    {
      "id": 1234,
      "city": "Medway",
      "country": "United Kingdom",
      "name": "Medway Youth Hostel",
      "url": "http://www.yha.org.uk",
      "contact": [
        {
          "email": "hari34@gmail.com",
          "phone": 6789435634
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3456,
      "city": "Texas",
      "country": "USA",
      "name": "Texas Youth Hostel",
      "url": "http://www.yha.org.uk",
      "contact": [
        {
          "email": "ram123@gmail.com",
          "phone": 876543219
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am very new to n1ql query, would anyone please help me to find the solution for inserting/Update an array to the object with in object. Example 1 is inserting an data to JSON, Example 2 is updating the data to Example 1 and follows...
1. Please help to get n1ql queries that satisfies above examples.
2. How to generate an UUID to id field in the document

Answer (score 1):

1) Appends array never checks if element already exist in the array

```
INSERT INTO default VALUES ("k01", { "details": [ { "id": 1234, "city": "Medway", "country": "United Kingdom", "name": "Medway Youth Hostel", "url": "http://www.yha.org.uk" }] });

UPDATE default AS d SET e.contact = [ { "email": "hari34@gmail.com", "phone": 6789435634 } ]
                           FOR e IN d.details WHEN e.id = 1234 END
WHERE META().id = "k01";

UPDATE default AS d SET e.contact = ARRAY_APPEND(e.contact,{ "email": "sri123@gmail.com", "phone": 9876655555 })
                           FOR e IN d.details WHEN e.id = 1234 END
WHERE META().id = "k01";

UPDATE default AS d SET d.details = ARRAY_APPEND(d.details,{ "id": 3456, "city": "Texas", "country": "USA", "name": "Texas Youth Hostel", "url": "http://www.yha.org.uk", "contact": [ { "email": "ram123@gmail.com", "phone": 876543219 } ] })
WHERE META().id = "k01";

SELECT * from default USE KEYS["k01"];
```

2) USE  UUID() function like below

```
INSERT INTO default VALUES ("k01", { "details": [ { "id": UUID(), "city": "Medway", "country": "United Kingdom", "name": "Medway Youth Hostel", "url": "http://www.yha.org.uk" }] });
```

Comment: How can i control the duplicate values, When i execute the query3 everytime fields are inserting with same values irrespective of elements  exists or not. please suggest me(Query). So that no duplicate appends will happen